# Android Studio: SQLite Insert Syntax Error Near "("

Tags: java, android, sqlite, syntax-error

I am trying to insert a new set of variables into a new database table using the method I have used for registering accounts which works successfully, however for the current table it is not working and I am not sure why.

This is the code class for the database creation:

```
public class DatabaseCreate extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


public DatabaseCreate(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DatabaseHandler.DB_CREATE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DatabaseHandler.DB_CREATE2);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DatabaseHandler.DB_CREATE3);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int v1, int v2) {

    Log.w("Handler", "Writing over old data from " + v1 + " to new " + v2 + " data, wiping all " + v1 + " data.");
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}}
```

This is the code for the database table that works:

```
static final String DB_CREATE = "create table " + "LOGIN" + "(" + "ID" + " integer primary key autoincrement," + "USERNAME text, PASSWORD text); ";
```

public void insertEntry(String u, String p){

```
    ContentValues newVal = new ContentValues();
    newVal.put("USERNAME", u);
    newVal.put("PASSWORD", p);
    db.insert("LOGIN", null, newVal);
```

}

This is the code for the tables that dont work:

```
static final String DB_CREATE2 = "create table " + "NEW_BAND" + "(" + "ID" + " integer primary key autoincrement," + "BAND_NAME text, HOMETOWN text, MEMBERS text, GENRE(S) text, YEARS_ACTIVE text, WEBSITE text); ";
static final String DB_CREATE3 = "create table " + "NEW_GIG" + "(" + "ID" + " integer primary key autoincrement," + "BAND_NAME text, CITY text, VENUE text, DATE text, TIME text, TICKETS text); ";
```

```
public void insertNewBand(String n, String h, String m, String g, String y, String w){

    ContentValues newVal = new ContentValues();
    newVal.put("BAND_NAME", n);
    newVal.put("HOMETOWN", h);
    newVal.put("MEMBERS", m);
    newVal.put("GENRE(S)", g);
    newVal.put("YEARS_ACTIVE", y);
    newVal.put("WEBSITE", w);
    db.insert("NEW_BAND", null, newVal);
}

public void insertNewGig(String b, String c, String v, String d, String t, String ti){

    ContentValues newVal = new ContentValues();
    newVal.put("BAND_NAME", b);
    newVal.put("CITY", c);
    newVal.put("VENUE", v);
    newVal.put("DATE", d);
    newVal.put("TIME", t);
    newVal.put("TICKETS", ti);
    db.insert("NEW_GIG", null, newVal);
}
```

Comment: As the error says you have an error in your SQL. You can’t have parentheses in your field names unless you escape them. Change the BAND(S) to bands. And don’t tag Android Studio, it’s just an IDE and doesn’t relate to the problem. Android is more appropriate tag.

Comment: Seems question was changed. It is now `GENRE(S)` that is an invalid identifier.

Comment: I feel so dumb, thank you for the help